# Finding the volume of an object

Tags: geometry

I need to find a volume of an object restricted with the following planes:

$$z=x^{2}+y^{2}$$
$$z=1$$

Ok, pretty easy, I'm going for the polar coordinates:

$0 < r < 1$
$0 < \phi < \frac{\pi}{2}$

This is clear and obvious, but when it comes to the z variable...well, I think it should be:

$x^{2}+y^{2} < z < 1$
But the notes say it's rather:
$r^{2} < z < 1$
Why is that so, where did the r came from?

Comment: I can't see that. If $x^{2}+y^{2}<z<1$ is true, and r = 1 = ...but wait, r should be a variable here...no, I can't see that.

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (I think that is what Ataraxia meant)

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it now, thanks! Actually, in polar coordinates $x^{2}+y^{2}$ becomes $r^{2}$

Comment: @khernik Yea, typo, sorry about that. kaine is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The limits in Cylindrical coordinates is as follows:

$$\theta|_0^{2\pi}, r|_{0}^1,z|_{r^2}^1$$  Note that the plane $z=1$ intersect $z=r^2=x^2+y^2$ at $x^2+y^2=1$. And that's why we choose above limits for $r$.

[image]

Comment: Each time I see these I get more and more envious of these nice graphs...+1

Comment: @BabakS.: I agree with DA, beautiful pictures! Congrats on answering over 1000 questions (wow) +1